# Erro 404 ao definir URL no mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Boas

Estou a tentar mudar os URL's no meu site conforme o exemplo abaixo do ficheiro .htaccess mas acabo por ir ter à página "Objecto não encontrado, Error 404" do localhost.

Eis o codigo do meu ficheiro .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^country/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)*/?$ country.php?country=$1 [NC,R]
```

Ou seja tou a tentar mudar a página country.php?country=Italy, para country/Italy.

O http.config do apache foi alterado com este codigo:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

E o .htaccess encontra-se na pasta htdocs do Xampp.

Obrigado pela vossa ajuda.

Comment: Alguem que possa ajudar?